# Sandbox Refresh button disappeared

Tags: sandbox-refresh

Since two weeks, sandbox 'Refresh' button has disappeared in all the 3 instances we have. Does it have anything to do with the Summer 16 release? I checked with my friends working in different companies and they do not have any such issues. Any one else having this issue?

[image: Sandbox page]

Comment: Perhaps your permissions changed? Do you still have `Modify All Data` or `Manage Sandbox`?

Comment: I'm the system administrator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to raise a case with Salesforce.  This usually happens when you run into a Licensing issue or number of sanboxes (specific to full box) available reaches to 0.  We had this issue before in one of our client org where it was part of Veeva.

We could get this resolved with a case raised with SFDC.

Answer (score 5):

I reached out to Salesforce and they said we are using two full copy sandboxes when we are entitled to only one. The refresh button will be grayed out until we delete the extra full copy sandbox.

Comment: I suggest you connect up to your salesforce success manager and understand your deal with them.

Comment: My manager is talking to the sales person. We didn't change anything with number of sandboxes during license negotiation. We trying to find what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When salesforce provides a temporary sandbox (courtesy Sandbox provided upon request for a certain period) and if it is not deleted, the Refresh button may disappear for all the sandboxes. Try deleting the courtesy sandbox, it should work.